# ejabberd won't look at my host_config option

Tags: ldap, ejabberd

I'm new with ejabberd. What I want is to have a host myhost.domain.com which has an ldap authentication method.

This all works fine if i modify the global options in AUTHENTICATION section in my ejabberd.cfg file. I am able to create two clients( defined in my LDAP directory ), and comunicate between them.

Like i said, this works fine. But by aplying this authentication method globaly, it means that every hostname that i declare must use that. So i'm looking at {host_config, "myhost.domain.com" ...} But somehow i can't get ejabberd to look at that configuration, it just skips it. If i declare it like: {xhost_config, ...}, than in my ejabberd.log file i get a bad return error( so it knows that the configuration is there, but it won't look at it).

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the problem. It turns out that ejabberd missed a file during installation.